# Import data from SQL Server 2008 to mongoDB database (failed batch script attempt)

Tags: mongodb, csv, batch-file, mongoimport

I want to import data from *SQL Server 2008* to a *mongoDB* database. As my data is too large, about 62500000 entries, I have tried lots of options and finally decided to use Excel. I imported data from SQL Server to Excel and then saved that Excel as CSV. Then I tried to import that CSV file to the mongoDB and that was successful.

But because of the limitation of Excel, I can only save data in Excel up to 1000000 entries, so I have generated 60 CSV files. I created a batch file, but it is not working. I want to import all 60 files at a single time by executing the batch file. My batch file code is:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin"
for /L %%a in (1,1,10) do (
   echo This is iteration %%a
   start "mongoimport --db testSQL --collection csvData --type csv --headerline --file C:\Users\it_vaibhavg\Desktop\Book%%a.csv"
)
pause
```

Or is there a better way to copy SQL Server 2008 data to a mongoDB?

Comment: `start` considers the first set of quotes it finds to be the window title. Add `""` directly after `start`.

Comment: i tried that too then also i am having problem it showing error 'Windows cannot find mongoimport --db testSQL --collection csvData --type csv --headerline --file C:\Users\it_vaibhavg\Desktop\Book%%a.csv. Make sure you typed the name correctly' @SomethingDark

Comment: `start "" "mongoimport" --db testSQL --collection csvData --type csv --headerline --file "C:\Users\it_vaibhavg\Desktop\Book%%a.csv"`. Read http://ss64.com/nt/start.html. Consider adding `/WAIT` option as well.

Comment: You may also need to use the full path to mongoimport.exe

Comment: Can't you just do a CSV export on SQL and then import the CSV into mongoDB using mongoport? why do you need Excel for that??

Comment: Thank you @aschipfl it worked.

Comment: @aschipfl how about posting your comment as an answer, and Vaibhav, how about marking that as the answer when he does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to copy SQL Server 2008 data to a mongoDB: you can do a CSV export on SQL, and then import the CSV file into mongoDB using mongoimport. This way you do not run into size limitations as with Excel.